# What's the differences between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_binary collation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set

I'm can't find the documentation of MySQL on this topic. Anyone can give some explanations please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-mysql.html)

> Collations have these general characteristics:
>
> Two different character sets cannot have the same collation.
>
> Each character set has one collation that is the default collation.
>   For example, the default collation for latin1 is latin1_swedish_ci.
>   The output for SHOW CHARACTER SET indicates which collation is the
>   default for each displayed character set.
>
> There is a convention for collation names: They start with the name of
>   the character set with which they are associated, they usually include
>   a language name, and they end with _ci (case insensitive), _cs (case
>   sensitive), or _bin (binary).
>
> In cases where a character set has multiple collations, it might not
>   be clear which collation is most suitable for a given application. To
>   avoid choosing the wrong collation, it can be helpful to perform some
>   comparisons with representative data values to make sure that a given
>   collation sorts values the way you expect.

[StackOverflow has a list of questions tagged utf-8 and collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf-8+collation)

[ServerFault only has one tagged utf-8 and collation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/utf-8+collation)

There is a website called efreedom.com that has links all around StackOverflow concerning utf8 : http://efreedom.com/Question/1-4784168/Change-Collation-Utf8-Bin-One-Go

Here is another site about collations as its place in the MySQL World : http://www.collation-charts.org/

Here is a link explaining binary collations : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html